# Java - Why is this implementation of a binary heap faster than the other?

Tags: java, performance, heap

After reading a bit about heaps/priority queues, I recently made my own implementation of one. Afterwards I decided to compare the performance of my implementation to that of one which I found in a book, and the results are a bit confusing to me. It appears that there is a vast performance difference between the insert methods of the two implementations.

I used this code to test both heaps:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000_0; i++) heap.insert(rnd.nextInt(1000));
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

When I run this with my heap implementation, I get a result of around 600ms. When I run it with the book's implementation I get around 1900ms. How can the difference possibly be this big? Surely there must be something wrong with my implementation.

My implementation:

```
public class Heap<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    private T[] array = (T[])new Comparable[10];
    private int size = 0;

    public void insert(T data) {
        if(size+1 > array.length) expandArray();

        array[size++] = data;
        int pos = size-1;
        T temp;

        while(pos != 0 && array[pos].compareTo(array[pos/2]) < 0) {
            temp = array[pos/2];
            array[pos/2] = array[pos];
            array[pos] = temp;
            pos /= 2;
        }
    }

    private void expandArray() {
        T[] newArray = (T[])new Comparable[array.length*2];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            newArray[i] = array[i];

        array = newArray;
    }
}
```

The book's implementation:

```
public class BooksHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

    private int currentSize;
    private AnyType [ ] array;

    public BinaryHeap( )
    {
        this( DEFAULT_CAPACITY );
    }

    public BinaryHeap( int capacity )
    {
        currentSize = 0;
        array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ capacity + 1 ];
    }

    public void insert( AnyType x )
    {
        if( currentSize == array.length - 1 )
            enlargeArray( array.length * 2 + 1 );

        int hole = ++currentSize;
        for( array[ 0 ] = x; x.compareTo( array[ hole / 2 ] ) < 0; hole /= 2 )
            array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
        array[ hole ] = x;
    }


    private void enlargeArray( int newSize )
    {
            AnyType [] old = array;
            array = (AnyType []) new Comparable[ newSize ];
            for( int i = 0; i < old.length; i++ )
                array[ i ] = old[ i ];        
    }
}
```

Edit: The book is "Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java" by Mark Allen Weiss. Third edition. ISBN: 0-273-75211-1.

Comment: Maybe you should improve your *measurement* technique? Where's your warmup, for example?

Comment: If you adjust for differing Constructors, `expand`/`enlarge` method names and Generic type names (`T/AnyType`), the only difference between these implementations is the BookHeap is adjusting the array and then placing the inserted object the correct slot, while your code starts by appending the inserted object to the end then adjusting the array back into a sorted order.  Thinking about the execution like this might make there similarity clearer.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I didn't know that using a loop like this could yield completely misleading results in a scenario like this. I still don't really understand why it gets it so wrong, but good to know regardless. I only tested one of the heaps per run, so this warmup time thing shouldn't apply, right?

Comment: No, that makes it even worse.   The environment of the computer it's running on will vary.   Read up on the perils of benchmarking (and especially microbenchmarking, which is what you're doing.    Basically, though, you need to make sure you've loaded both classes `and used both methods many times` before you actually begin timing.  And then you should run the whole test a bunch of times, varying the order of class load.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, your code measured with JMH:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@OperationsPerInvocation(Measure.SIZE)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Fork(1)
public class Measure
{
  static final int SIZE = 4_000_000;
  private Random rnd;

  @Setup public void setup() {
    rnd  = new Random();
  }

  @Benchmark public Object heap() {
    Heap<Integer> heap = new Heap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) heap.insert(rnd.nextInt());
    return heap;
  }

  @Benchmark public Object booksHeap() {
    BooksHeap<Integer> heap = new BooksHeap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) heap.insert(rnd.nextInt());
    return heap;
  }

  public static class Heap<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    private T[] array = (T[])new Comparable[10];
    private int size = 0;

    public void insert(T data) {
      if(size+1 > array.length) expandArray();

      array[size++] = data;
      int pos = size-1;
      T temp;

      while(pos != 0 && array[pos].compareTo(array[pos/2]) < 0) {
        temp = array[pos/2];
        array[pos/2] = array[pos];
        array[pos] = temp;
        pos /= 2;
      }
    }

    private void expandArray() {
      T[] newArray = (T[])new Comparable[array.length*2];
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        newArray[i] = array[i];
      array = newArray;
    }
  }

  public static class BooksHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
  {
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

    private int currentSize;
    private AnyType [ ] array;

    public BooksHeap()
    {
      this( DEFAULT_CAPACITY );
    }

    public BooksHeap( int capacity )
    {
      currentSize = 0;
      array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ capacity + 1 ];
    }

    public void insert( AnyType x )
    {
      if( currentSize == array.length - 1 )
        enlargeArray( array.length * 2 + 1 );

      int hole = ++currentSize;
      for( array[ 0 ] = x; x.compareTo( array[ hole / 2 ] ) < 0; hole /= 2 )
        array[ hole ] = array[ hole / 2 ];
      array[ hole ] = x;
    }


    private void enlargeArray( int newSize )
    {
      AnyType [] old = array;
      array = (AnyType []) new Comparable[ newSize ];
      for( int i = 0; i < old.length; i++ )
        array[ i ] = old[ i ];
    }
  }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark          Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
Measure.booksHeap  avgt    5  62,712 ± 23,633  ns/op
Measure.heap       avgt    5  62,784 ± 44,228  ns/op
```

They are exactly the same.

Moral of the exercise: don't think you can just write a loop and call it a *benchmark*. Measuring anything meaningful within a complex, self-optimizing runtime like HotSpot is an incredibly difficult challenge, best left to an expert benchmark tool like JMH.

As a side note, you could shave some 20% off your times (in both implementations) if you use `System.arraycopy` instead of the manual loop. Embarassingly, this wasn't my idea—IntelliJ IDEA's automatic inspection suggested that, and converted the code on its own :)

Answer (score 2):

Taking the testing of implementations part of this question, how you are testing these implementations can explain a lot of any difference, consider this example.  When I place your Heap in a class called `OPHeap` and the book's heap in a class called `BookHeap` and then test in this order:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String ...args) {
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            BookHeap<Integer> heap = new BookHeap<Integer>();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000_0; i++) heap.insert(rnd.nextInt(1000));
            System.out.println("Book's Heap:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            OPHeap<Integer> heap = new OPHeap<Integer>();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000_0; i++) heap.insert(rnd.nextInt(1000));
            System.out.println("  OP's Heap:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
Book's Heap:1924
  OP's Heap:1171
```

However when I swap the order of the tests I get this output:

```
  OP's Heap:1867
Book's Heap:1515
```

This is called "Warm-up" and you can learn a lot of ways to deal with it from [this article](http://stuq.nl/weblog/2009-01-28/why-many-java-performance-tests-are-wrong).  Also anytime you are using Random in a test you should define a seed value, so your "pseudo random" results are predictable.